wagmi `useSignTypedData` hangs in pending with WalletConnect and Gnosis Safe
With wagmi useSignTypedData, WalletConnect, and Gnosis Safe, the useSignTypedData hook doesn't detect the Safe contract's emitted SignMsg event and hangs in pending until timing out.
wagmi latest (2.10.9), @walletconnect/ethereum-provider latest (2.13.3), and @walletconnect/modal latest (2.6.2).
What's the correct way to use wagmi signature APIs for Safe signature generation and EIP-1271 verification?
This issue is the same as https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/4464

This seems like the problem comes from WalletConnect; a work-around has been found here: https://github.com/orgs/WalletConnect/discussions/5175#discussioncomment-10016000 ; if it applies, could you confirm it worked? Thanks in advance  Best, Louis
